# OSError - Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, django, apache, unix

I am trying to upload image through admin page, but it keeps saying:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/to/my/site/media/userfolder/2014/05/26'
```

the folders  `userfolder/2014/05/26` are created dynamically while uploading.

In Traceback, i found that the error is occuring during this command:

In /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py Line 157. while calling

```
mkdir(name, mode)
```

meaning, it cannot create any folder as it doesnot have the permission to do this

I have OpenSuse as OS in Server. In httpd.conf, i have this:

```
<Directory /path/to/my/site/media>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Do I have to chmod or chown something?

Comment: Make sure the directory `/path/to/my/site/media` is writable by web server process.

Comment: `ps aux | grep apache` will show you what user own the process.

Comment: @falsetru this shows me ``root``. so this is my django code, right?

Comment: What about `ps aux | grep httpd | grep -v grep` or `ps aux | grep apache | grep -v grep` ?

Comment: @falsetru 2nd command doesnt show anything, 1st one shows many processes the first one is of root, the rest is of httpd.

Comment: You should change ownership of the directory `/path/to/my/site/media` or change permission so that `httpd` user can write there.

Comment: `chown -R httpd:httpd /path/to/my/site/media` (the second `httpd` is group name. You need to change it if the group of the `httpd` is different from `httpd`)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to change the directory permission so that web server process can change the directory.

- To change ownership of the directory, use `chown`:

  ```
  chown -R user-id:group-id /path/to/the/directory
  ```
- To see which user own the web server process (change `httpd` accordingly):

  ```
  ps aux | grep httpd | grep -v grep
  ```

  OR

  ```
  ps -efl | grep httpd | grep -v grep
  ```

Comment: I'm using gunicorn. I get same error message. I want to give gunicorn read/write access to a folder under /home/portfolio. How do I go about it?

Comment: @Rexford, You'd better post a separated question with `gevent` tag.

Comment: @falsetru I solved the issue by changing the owner of main folders and it's subdirectory/files to www-data. I am using flask+apache for backend server. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 24):

This may also happen if you have a slash before the folder name:

```
path = '/folder1/folder2'

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/folder1'
```

comes up with an error but this one works fine:

```
path = 'folder1/folder2'
```

Comment: It is worth explaining _why_ this happens. A `/` before the folder name in Unix indicates that the folder should exist in the root directory, which also houses all the major sensitive system folders e.g. `/usr/`, `/bin/`, etc. (try it, do `cd /` and see where you land up). Ordinary processes are not permitted to modify the root directory. Omitting a leading `/` defaults the folder to the current working directory, which is perfectly safe and which Unix will do for you.

Comment: @mjp When i tried to remove the first slash from 'folder1/' it indeed worked and the error was gone, however i have no idea were that folder is now? So where is it? How do i access it? thanks

Comment: I created a folder called folder1 in you current directory

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are facing problem when a download request is made by the maybe_download function call in base.py file.

There is a conflict in the permissions of the temporary files and I myself couldn't work out a way to change the permissions, but was able to work around the problem.

Do the following...

- Download the four .gz files of the MNIST data set from the link ( http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ )
- Then make a folder names MNIST_data (or your choice in your working directory/ site packages folder in the tensorflow\examples folder).
- Directly copy paste the files into the folder.
- Copy the address of the folder (it probably will be 
  ( C:\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\MNIST_data  ))
- Change the "\" to "/" as "\" is used for escape characters, to access the folder locations.
- Lastly, if you are following the tutorials, your call function would be **( mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True) )** ;
  change the **"MNIST_data/"** parameter to your **folder location**. As in my case would be *( mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("C:/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/MNIST_data", one_hot=True) )*

Then it's all done.
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to ensure the file is not open anywhere else on your machine.

Comment: This only applies to Windows. It looks like this question is directed at Linux. There these restrictions do not exist

Answer (score 1):

supplementing @falsetru's answer : run id in the terminal to get your user_id and group_id

Go the directory/partition where you are facing the challenge.
Open terminal, type id then press enter.
This will show you your user_id and group_id

then type

`chown -R user-id:group-id .`

Replace user-id and group-id

`.` at the end indicates current partition / repository

// chown -R 1001:1001 . (that was my case)

Comment: Please add some more detail so that your answer stands on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
sudo cp /source /destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Just close the file in case it is opened in the background. The error disappears by itself

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked out for me here when I was using python 3 os package for performing operations on a directory where I didn't have sufficient permissions and access to got resolved by running the python file with sudo (root) i.e.:

```
sudo python python_file_name.py
```

Any other utility that you might also plan on using to chmod or chown that directory would also only work when you run it with sudo.

```
# file_name.py
base_path = "./parent_dir/child_dir/"
user = os.stat(base_path).st_uid # for getting details of the current user owner of the dir
group = os.stat(base_path).st_gid # for getting details of the current group owner of the dir

print("Present owner and group of the specified path")
print("Owner:", user)
print("Group:", group)
os.chown(base_path, user, group) # change directory permissions

print("\nOwner id of the file:", os.stat(base_path).st_uid)
print("Group id of the file:", os.stat(base_path).st_gid)
os.mkdir(base_path+file_name,mode=0o666)
```

run the above file with sudo.

```
sudo python file_name.py
```

Hope this answer works out for you.

Forever indebted to stackoverflow and the dev community. All hail the devs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have typed the path correctly, if not try using "//" twice instead of "/" once, it worked for me,

sorry if still not got it, try and keep looking.

Comment: Instead of `//` you probably mean to say ``\\`` as you might be using Windows?

Comment: May be, Yes working on windows, 
please check the screenshot by clicking on the link : https://prnt.sc/CNxBSj5gzOdl