# Cannot upgrade Pip. Permission denied. Why?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip on my iMac, but I keep getting a permission denied error. I'm the admin, so I don't know what I've done wrong.

```
iMac:~ me$ pip install --upgrade pip
    You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    Collecting pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=5ff9fec0be479e4e36df467556deed4d
      Downloading pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
        100% |################################| 1.1MB 181kB/s 
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 6.0.8
        Uninstalling pip-6.0.8:
          Exception:
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
              status = self.run(options, args)
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
              root=options.root_path,
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 543, in install
              requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 667, in uninstall
              paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
              renames(path, new_path)
            File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 316, in renames
              shutil.move(old, new)
            File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
              rmtree(src)
            File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
              rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
            File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
              onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
            File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
              os.remove(fullname)
          OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'
```

I don't know what I've done wrong here as an upgrade seem fairly straightforward.

Thanks,

Comment: How about running it with 'sudo' in front?!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`pip` installations require elevation

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Just because you are currently using an admin account doesn't mean the command will run with elevation, unless you specify `sudo`

Comment: FWIW you should mention that it not good practice to use sudo with pip but virtual environment

Comment: `WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try 'pip install --user' instead.`

Comment: I use `python3 -m pip install pip --user --upgrade` in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `sudo` since you are upgrading pip "globally". I prefer to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and let Homebrew manage everything.

1. Install Xcode from the App Store
2. Install Homebrew - `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Install Python - `brew install python`, which also installs pip.

With this setup, everything is installed locally, which doesn't require you to run `sudo`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can also install Python 3 with `brew install python3`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two ways:

1. `chown -R user /path/to/file` a more detailed information can be found in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870808/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied) post, while it doesn't relate to the exact problem it deals with the same issue
2. Quick and dirty way just do `pip install --upgrade pip` as already mentioned. However, many users will suggest against that.