# How can i get rid of pip install with OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: macos, pip

I've been trying to install something by pip in macos, but there are always some
errors.
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpq0h.png)

And I know some tips like using 'sudo' to get rid of it.
But how can I install without using 'sudo' ?
Why did it happen actually?

Comment: Please post the actual error code and not an image of the error code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to this thread [ErrNo 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870808/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied).

Error no. 13 mainly happens due to not having permissions to perform the task or the command executed at OS level.

You can try changing the folder structure from

```
/dir1/dir2
```

to

```
dir1/dir2
```

as suggested by user [mjp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402386/mjp) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295798/5668215).

Or you can use

> sudo

to overcome this.