# os.chdir OSError(13, 'Permission denied') for ampps

Tags: php, python, apache, exec, ampps

I am calling python script `script.py` through php script `index.php` by following command:

```
$tmp = exec("python script.py xyz");
```

Now, in python script `script.py`, I am trying to change the directory, which is symlink of folder:

```
try:
    os.chdir('softlink')
except:
    var = sys.exc_info()
    print var
```

Below error is coming while executing

```
<type 'exceptions.OSError'>, OSError(13, 'Permission denied'), <traceback object at >
```

I changed permissions for `softlink`, `script.py` and `index.html` according to similar question [OSError - Errno 13 Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870808/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied) , which are:

```
ls -la 
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ampps    ampps 1819 Nov  8 21:08 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ampps    ampps 4391 Nov  8 21:15 script.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ampps    ampps   39 Nov  8 20:14 softlink -> 
/local/mnt/workspace/manifest/
```

I am not getting what else permission the folder or symlink requires, so that ampps server can access the folder. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try running the python script directly from the command line?

Comment: `/local/mnt/workspace/manifest/` what filesystem does that point to? I mean, if the `ampps` user doesn't have permission to read filesystem mounted by someone else that might be the problem.

Comment: @Samarth Yes. From command line this is working absolutely fine.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This folder is created by me. And I changed permission too of this folder.

drwxrwxrwx  3 ampps    ampps 4096 Nov  8 20:25 manifest

Comment: So you can confirm `/local/mnt/workspace` is not an actual mounted filesystem? In that case, why did you name it like that (not that it counts in the context of your question)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Actually, I know less about filesystem. Can you please help with command to check filesystem and permissions. Thanks a lot.
findmnt  -l command  returns /usr2/piyush.

Comment: *"`findmnt -l` command returns `/usr2/piyush`"* if you mean without any other parameter, than it looks like `/local/mnt/workspace/manifest/` is not an actual mounted filesystem

Comment: Sorry, more specifically `findmnt  -l | grep 'mnt'` command returns ` /local/mnt ext4 rw,relatime,data=or` and `findmnt  -l | grep 'piyush'` command returns `/usr2/piyush nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183315/discussion-between-piyush-balwani-and-federico-klez-culloca).