# permissions/user problem when I call a python script from php

Tags: php, python, permissions

I would like to open a python script from php. My php user is "user23" which is the main user account on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop.
**start.php**:

```php
    <?php 
    echo 'php user: ' . get_current_user();
    $output=shell_exec("python ./test.py");
    echo'<br>python script user: ';
    echo($output);
    echo '<br>Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
    ?>
```

**test.py:**

```py
    import getpass
    import os
    print(getpass.getuser())
    os.mkdir(getpass.getuser())
```

PHP output if i open http://localhost/start.php with chrome:

```
php user: user23
python script user: root
Current PHP version: 7.1.32
```

So the script works, but the 'root' folder is not created. **PHP error log:**

```
  File "./test.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.mkdir(getpass.getuser())
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'root'
```

I do not understand why the php and the python users are different (*user23,root*) and how it is possible that the root user has no permission to create the folder (*Errno 13] Permission denied: 'root'*).

if I open the start.php the python user will be user23 and the folder created perfectly.

```
$ php start.php
php user: user23<br>python script user: user23
<br>Current PHP version: 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
```

I use xampp if it's matter. I hope you can help me, I'm totally lost right now. *Sorry for my english.*

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870808/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it help you 
php code with sudo

```
shell_exec('echo "PASS" | sudo -u root -S python .test.py');
```