# Importing JPG files from a Folder for PyTorch transformation (Another error)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I just recently posted a question about a file path error in which I thought I resolved... the folder that I have contains .jpg files. For some reason, i'm getting a new error:

> RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders of: C:\Users\Lyn\Desktop\UTKFaceDataSet\Train_Set
> Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp

Here is my modified code:

```
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Lyn\\Desktop\\UTKFaceDataSet"
train_dir = data_dir + '\\Train_Set'
test_dir = data_dir + '\\Test_Set'

training_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(100),
                                          transforms.ToTensor()])
testing_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                                         transforms.ToTensor()])

#Load the datasets with ImageFolder
training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=training_transforms)
testing_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(test_dir, transform=testing_transforms)
```

Comment: Could you try this: `import os; os.path.isdir(train_dir)` and see if it returns `True`?

Comment: @Ivan I'll give it a try! Thanks for responding!

Comment: (^ this was not a solution, just to check your directory actually exists). You can also print out `os.listdir(train_dir)` and tell us what you find.

Comment: @Ivan it returns true

Comment: ok, and what about `listdir`?

Comment: @Ivan yes! it prints out all JPG files ex: ['s3.jpg', 's32.jpg', 's34.jpg', 's35.jpg', 's38.jpg', 's4.jpg', 's40.jpg', 's5.jpg', 's6.jpg', 's7.jpg']

Comment: Now we need to check that those are actual jpg files. You can do that with `import imghdr; imghdr.what(<path_to_file_>) == jpg`.

Comment: @Ivan, im getting an error - [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Lyn\\Desktop\\UTKFaceDataSet\\Test_Set'

Comment: Have a look here, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870808/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: As your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133426/importing-jpg-files-from-a-folder-for-pytorch-transformation) (where I had also edited the tags), this one is about a file/folder access from Python issue, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning`; kindly avoid using these tags in similar cases (the ones left here are more than enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your directory structure in the following format to use the [`datasets.ImageFolder()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder):

```py
dataset
   train_dataset
      dogs
         a.png, b.png
      cats
         c.png, d.png
   valid_dataset
      dogs
         e.png, f.png
      cats
         g.png, h.png
```

```py
train_dir = 'dataset/train_dataset/'
training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=training_transforms)
```

I used two categories (dogs and cats), but it could be one also.